# How to run unit test with in memory Kombu with an infinite loop running drain events?

Tags: python, pytest, infinite-loop, in-memory, kombu

Hi I am new to Python & I got issue with unit test involving Kombu & inifinite while loop.

I use Python 3.9 with the latest Kombu library & PyTest.

I got a microservice class which has private Queue, Consumer attributes. It also has a public method called `start`, which runs an infinite while loop calling `drain_events` to pool for incoming messages from RabbitMq.

The Consumer has a callback method which receives an incoming message from a queue called `test-queue`, then publishes another message to topic called `processed-message`

When I use in-memory connection in unit test, after I call `start` method from the microservice class, the unit test does not continue as the thread blocks at `drain_events` method.

1. How do I write unit test with a microservice running an infinite loop with drain-events?
2. How do I check whether there is a message published to topic `processed-message` when in-memory connection is used in unit test?
3. How do I put a message in `test-queue` in unit test if the microservice class does not expose Queue, Consumer attribute?